# ASP.NET MVC add user to his 'family' after usermanger has created/inserted him

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-identity

I'm making a registration form for the head of the family. So when someone registers a user and a family is made. The user is inserted in the DB by the Usermanager. After this i want to make a new family and add the user to this family. The Problem is, that with the code below he complains that the user allready exists.

Hope you guys can help me out. :)

Family class:

```
public class Familie
{
    public int familieId { get; set; }
    public virtual Adres adres { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> contactPersonen { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> kinderen { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser gezinsHoofd { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Registreer_Ouder(ContactPersViewModelmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.email,
                Email = model.email,
                voorNaam = model.voorNaam,
                achterNaam = model.achterNaam,
                PhoneNumber = model.gsm,
                PasswordHash = model.password,
            };

            Adres adres = new Adres
            {
                gemeente = db.Gemeente.Find(model.gemeente),
                nummer = model.nummer,
                straat = model.straat
            };
            Familie familie = new Familie
            {
                adres = adres
            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName);
                var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "GezinsHoofd");

                try { 
                    db.Familie.Add(familie);
                    db.Familie.Find(familie.familieId).gezinsHoofd = user;
                    db.SaveChanges(); // ERROR IS HERE
                }
                catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    // Just reading the exception for now.. 
                    throw;
                }
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Bevestig uw registratie", "Om te bevestigen klik <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">hier</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Welkom", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Execption:

[image: Error]

In browser
[image: Error2]

Comment: Why are you fetching the user from the database again (i.e. `currentUser`)? Use the same `user` instance for everything, and that may fix your issue.

Comment: Does not make a difference.. Same problem.

Comment: if you comment out this: `db.Familie.Find(familie.familieId).gezinsHoofd = user;` does that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it does.. But that's the thing. I need to get the user within the family.. gezinshoofd ( head of the family) is an applicationUser.  Surely i don't need to save an int in the family class? EF does that for me in the background right?

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET identity is sometimes a little bit tricky... The point is that you are adding a user with `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password)`. This method adds a user to the database but there's no reference for the user in the current database context for now.

If you assign the `user` to an element in the model (`db.Familie.Find(familie.familieId).gezinsHoofd = user`), EF tries to add the user again to the database. What you need to do is to load the created user from the database and add the user to the family element:

```
// some code ignored for readability
try { 
    db.Familie.Add(familie);
    // load user explicitly from database to include in the context
    var dbUser = db.ApplicationUser.Find(currentUser.Id);
    db.Familie.Find(familie.familieId).gezinsHoofd = dbUser;
    db.SaveChanges(); // There should not be any error here :)
 }
 catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
 {
     // Just reading the exception for now.. 
     throw;
 }
```

Comment: Or, just `.Attach` the existing user to the `Users` DbSet, and save the extra query.

Comment: It should be, but that's easy enough to check. Just debug and check it after the call to `SaveChanges`.

Comment: If i do it this way, he's getting a NullRef error when he is saving. Is it not the same if i use the 'currentUser' in stead of getting it again from db? Looks the same if i compare them. 
db.Users.Find(currentUser.Id); --> the ID is 0 - he has not received one yet? When does he get one?